# Send and Receive SMS from my Website

Tags: web-services, sms

The way I plan to use it is:

1. At the seminar, have people send SMS to a number to vote.
2. On the backend (assuming that the data comes back to my Web server), I will display the voting results on my Web site.
3. After say 10 minutes, I would like to press a button on my Web site so ONE of the people who sent an SMS earlier receive an SMS saying that person is a winner.

I'm an ASP .Net developer, so I just need an API to code against. One such company I saw that does this (but is limited to US) is:

```
* http://www.twilio.com/sms/
```

Do you know any international providers that are similar to Twilio SMS? I'm based in Sydney, Australia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used SMSGlobal http://www.smsglobal.com before. Check out their API (the documentation is available on the website) to see if they have this functionality - I think from memory they do.

Comment: Checking out SMSglobal now. The other 2 providers I've found is ClickATell and Tropo.